# .nuget folder why solutions have it?

Tags: c#, nuget

at work we do not use nuget and even though in my personal projects i use it ,i dont understand why many solutions I download all have it,typically with 3 files

Nuget.config,exe and target.

Can somebody explain why people add this folder to their solutions?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That folder was a key player in NuGet package restore in the good old days (NuGet.targets is the proof). But since the new restore mechanism is in place, only the NuGet.exe is useful.

You might read more from NuGet.org,

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Update:

> The linked article was updated and moved to [Microsoft
>   Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore).
>
> MSBuild 15 also adds NuGet package restore support if you read the above carefully.

Comment: hi,why is it NuGet.exe useful?do you still had it to your solution?

Comment: Without the command line tool, anyone without an IDE (Visual Studio/Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop) will not be able to easily restore NuGet packages (via nuget.exe restore your.sln). So yes, I still drop it in my projects, such as https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib

Comment: I would say `NuGet.config` is still useful and in some cases even required (if you are using any NuGet repositories except official one). It allows you to configure NuGet repositories where to search packages during restore.

Comment: @OleksandrKobylianskyi as restore is now in script, you can also set NuGet sources via command line "sources" switch, https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/nuget.exe-cli-reference and that makes the config file unnecessary.

Comment: That's true. But I guess you'd also want Visual Studio to be able to restore packages by itself for local development. So, `NuGet.config` is convenient way to achieve that: it is recognized by VS auto restore and can be passed to command-line `nuget.exe` call. And you end up having only ONE place to specify NuGet sources.

Answer (score 4):

As of nuget 2.7+, this folder is no longer needed and can be safely deleted.  Futhermore, if you use the Visual Studio command line prompt, you should be able to access nuget.exe from there, as well as, within Visual Studio from the Package Manager.

To enable automatic package restore in projects that used nuget 2.6 or before, you might need to manually delete the following from the bottom of your *.csproj files:

```
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.214\build\MSBuildTasks.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.214\build\MSBuildTasks.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Wow, this is unclear. You mean manually add the following to your nuget 2.6 or earlier solution? Your XML points to a .nuget folder that you say supposedly is no longer used after 2.7.

Comment: @gravidThoughts - To get your projects up to modern nuget standards, you should REMOVE the XML tags I pointed out.  I hope this clarifies.

Comment: It did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add something to Lex Li's answer. Another important file in the `.nuget` folder is the `nuget.config` file, especially if you are using nuget packages from other feeds other than nuget.org

Let's suppose that you have configured another package source as follows:

[image: Nuget Package Sources]

When you are adding or restoring packages on your local machine everything will work fine because nuget knows where to get the packages. When you're compiling your solution as part of a build on a Continuous Integration (CI) server (such as Visual Studio Team Services) the restore/install of the nuget packages could fail because the CI server doesn't know where to get the packages from!

So if you add the package sources to `.nuget/nuget.config`:

[image: Nuget.config with custom package sources]

You can then use the config file to restore/install the nuget packages - this is how I do it in Visual Studio Team Services:

[image]